# What is the best way to understand of the efficiency of my program other than load average?

Tags: linux, performance, cpu-usage, load-average

Consider the following scenarios:

1. I have only one process running on the machine and from resources like top gives 100% CPU usage which is good. I'm efficiently using the CPU.
2. I have two processes each of them taking 50% CPU. I'm still using the CPU efficiently as the total is hitting 100%.
3. I have N (relatively large number) processes running on the machine. Since the CPU is busy. My process may not hit 100% CPU still makes sense as the processor is busy too.
4. Now let's say there is only one process on the machine and still the CPU usage doesn't hit 100% CPU. Assume the cause is due to a bad program (too much IO or the program is simply doing nothing).

How do I detect case 4? The load average is not a good metric because it takes the average at different times.

Is there any metric or method that I can use to quantify how efficiently my program is using the CPU both under no-load conditions and fully loaded conditions?

Answer (score 2):

"Efficiency" is probably best described as "producing the maximum amount of useful results, using the minimum amount of resources".

If a program's purpose is processing data between files, then "too much IO" is not a measure of inefficiency -- it is the whole purpose of that specific program.

Likewise, "100% CPU usage" may not be good at all: it may just be a symptom of a seriously inefficient algorithm. With a better insight into the problem being solved, or even rewriting the same algorithm in a different language, you might only need 5% of the CPU to accomplish the same task.

IIRC, Load Average has very little to do with CPU usage. It basically measures the length of a scheduler's queue of ready-to-run jobs. But it has no idea whether any of those jobs are needing 10 microseconds of CPU before they yield, or ten seconds.

It is usual to measure overall program performance in isolation, and to profile it and improve it to meet expectations. For live running, the aim is to achieve a mix of processes which play nicely together, and to establish the point at which they start interfering with each other excessively (and schedulers do a rather good job for most workloads). That leads to demand management, and ultimately to a cost/benefit analysis  to justify a bigger box.

I did once have a manager who was really concerned that the Windows Idle Process was consuming about 97% of the CPU. They actually proposed setting up a project to make it more efficient. I had to choke back the laughter as I left the room.